# How to remove +-----+ from mysql query result

Tags: mysql, linux

Just wondering if there's a command line argument in mysql to remove the lines surrounding a mysql query result.

For one of my recent queries, I got this back:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1016442 |
+----------+
```

Since I'd like to use this result in my shell script to do something else with it, I'd like it to just return the value, and not the +-----+ and | characters surrounding it.  Is it possible to do this or do I have to find a way to parse around it?  Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: I was hoping there was a mysql command line option to easily return just the result.  If not, then I'll use sed, awk, grep like someone mentioned in the comments  =)

Comment: `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, tries any of these

Comment: @EdHeal, no, I didn't try that yet.  I was hoping there was some command line option for mysql such that it didn't add those things and just returned the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `-s` for what you want.

```
$ mysql   -s
mysql> SELECT NOW();
NOW()
2014-04-25 10:11:57
```

`-s` means `silent`

```
$ mysql --help
...
-s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
```

Also you can skip column header with `-N`

```
$ mysql -s -N
mysql> SELECT NOW();
2014-04-25 10:14:49
```